# getting invalid characters in the "path"

Tags: c#

```
System.ArgumentException: invalid characters in the "path".
```

em System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
   em System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   em System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   em System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   em System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
   em System.IO.File.InternalAppendAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
   em System.IO.File.AppendAllText(String path, String contents)
   em Loader.Program.Main(String[] args) na C:\Users\Muni\source\repos\encrypt\encrypt\Program.cs:linha 44

line 44

```
string name = Environment.UserName;
string temp = "C:\\Users\\" + name + "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\setup1.bat";
string tempe = new WebClient().DownloadString("website/setup1.txt");
                    File.AppendAllText(tempe, temp);
```

Comment: Might help to know what `name` is

Comment: If you really want a temporary file path, you should be using `string temp = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "setup1.bat");` instead.

Comment: its the name of the pc nothing to do with that                         string name = Environment.UserName;

Comment: What is the value of `name`?

Comment: @DanWilson nothing to do with the code but its the name of the current pc that is running it `                        string name = Environment.UserName;`

Comment: You also have your `File.AppendAllText` arguments backwards, it should be `File.AppendAllText(temp, tempe);`

Comment: @S1L3nT the value of name is likely what your problem is.  Post the exact value of `name`, it does not matter that it comes from `Environment.UserName`, we need to know if it contains an invalid character

Comment: @RonBeyer okay ill try that

Comment: @maccettura i already added into the code

Comment: @S1L3nT like I said, I dont need to know the code that assigns name.  We need to know the **value** of the `name` variable

Comment: @maccettura i think that u dont understand its just the path nothing to do with the error but its the name of your current username if u put string name = Enviroment.UserName; then console.write(name); it will output your pc's name

Comment: yea the error is because the arguments are backwards btw thanks for the downvotes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`File.AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx) arguments are backwards:

> public static void AppendAllText(
>           string path,
>           string contents
>       )

```
string temp = "C:\\Users\\" + name + "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\setup1.bat";
string tempe = new WebClient().DownloadString("website/setup1.txt");
                    File.AppendAllText(temp, tempe);
```

Would work as long as the path is accessible. You should not use string concatenation to create paths, use:

```
string temp = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "setup1.bat");
string tempe = new WebClient().DownloadString("website/setup1.txt");
                    File.AppendAllText(temp, tempe);
```

Instead... `Path.GetTempPath` will return the temporary file path for the current user. `Path.Combine` combines the path with the proper path separators.